# Maintaining different structure on each branch, but update both files

Tags: git, github, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

There are two branches with different structure but the same files (to some extent).

I want to update both with no copy & paste (which I'm doing now).

For example,

**Branch A**

`folder
    └another folder
                 └ my working dir (with some folders, and files)
                   └ some folders
                   │            └ some files(like a.txt, ...)
                   └ some folders`

**Branch B**

`folder
     └another folder
     └another folder
     └another folder
                   └another folder
                                 └ my working dir (with some folders, and files)
                                   └ some folders
                                   │            └ some files(like a.txt, ...)
                                   └ some folders`

1. For already existing files, I know Git can chase them and update them, but what about deleting files, and adding files? It doesn't track them and put them where they are supposed to be.
2. Can you tell me the exact example command like git commit [A branch], something like that?

Comment: If this is two branches of the same project, you're probably doing it wrong, and we'd need to know why you want to do it like this. If you can explain this, readers can get a better sense of your actual problem, and show you how to do it so that the folder structures are the same for all branches.

Answer (score 0):

okay, i think i need to explain more about the situation i have now.
i'm not charge of the whole project but it's about the difference between new version of the project and commercial(now servicing) one.

we are thinking of expanding the service via international one, so we added some different language model. it made our project need more complex structure.

but we want to update both versions as new.

*i cannot comment cause i don't have 50 reputation.

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.